# Download all tiles in Bounding Box using Cloudmade Ruby API

Tags: ruby, cloudmade

Can anybody supply an example of downloading all tiles between say zoom 10-18, inside a bounding box,

I'm trying to do this using the [Ruby API](http://developers.cloudmade.com/documentation/ruby-lib/index.html) but i can't seem to make sense of any of it, i can see how to download a single tile, how to make a boundingbox, but not how to use a bounding box to download all tiles inside it to use offline maps in my iPhone app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted this [perl script](http://search.cpan.org/~rotkraut/Geo-OSM-Tiles-0.04/) to Ruby and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Look into TileService class. It has methods #get_xy_tile, #latlon2tilenums. That's all you need.
Convert (lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2) to (x1, y1), (x2, y2) with #latlon2tilenums.
x(s) and y(s) are integers.
Now you have to simple loop from min(x1, x2) to max(x1, x2), do the same for y(s) and that's it.

If you write this function you can send it to authors of API, i.e. me ;), and we commit it to the trunk.

Comment: Thanks Igor, i have a working Ruby script which i will send to you!

Comment: i reviewed the method, and i do not think it should be included in the API. we can discuss it if necessary.